# Is it possible to achieve this conversion with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach (var mkTPL in personalTemplate.MarketsType) {
    foreach (var mkDB in currentPrintRow.Markets) {
        if (mkTPL.IDMarketType == mkDB.IDMarketType) {
            foreach (var selTPL in mkTPL.Selections) {
                foreach (var selDB in mkDB.Selections) {
                    if (selTPL.IdSelectionType == selDB.IdSelectionType) {
                        selTPL.OddOrResultValue = selDB.OddOrResultValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the solution I've reached by myself

```
foreach (var mkTPL1 in personalTemplate.MarketsType)
            {
                foreach (var selTPL in mkTPL1.Selections)
                {
                    selTPL.OddOrResultValue = (from mkTPL in personalTemplate.MarketsType
                        join mkDB in currentPrintRow.Markets on mkTPL.IDMarketType equals mkDB.IDMarketType
                        from selDB in mkDB.Selections
                        where selTPL.IdSelectionType == selDB.IdSelectionType
                        select selTPL.OddOrResultValue).SingleOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible to convert that to LINQ.

Comment: sure, you can do plenty of magic with linq, but how about adding the streamlined version of your classes that you want to use in the query?

Comment: @DanDohotaru: of course, I will edit

Comment: it seems you want to change the elements in `mkTPL.Selections`. Note that LINQ is a **query** language, not a *modifiying* language.

Comment: Linq is usually not for actions that modify fields, but for *queries* (that's the 'q' in 'linq', so you might not have a linq one-liner for that.

Comment: @Pac0 - I would disagree with that.  Yes, the 'q' is for 'queries', but LINQ is modeled after SQL queries which are perfectly capable of making modifications to the data (`update` query!).  In LINQ, you can have a single statement that makes big changes to the underlying data, or even returns a collection of entirely different structures.  LINQ is not just about querying the data in the sense of read queries.

Comment: @Pac0 What you said is correct. However, you can use LINQ to retrieve a list of items to be changed, and then change it inside a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - you can use `foreach` to perform operations where you change the data in the collection you are processing.   You can use `select` or `join` to return entirely new structures that are only derived from the original collection data, making as much changes as you want to the data.  To think of LINQ as being "usually not for actions that modify fields" is too limiting to what LINQ can actually do.

Comment: So the solution I found in the question was also nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to "flatten" these `foreach` loops with LINQ's joins. If you have large amounts of data, this should speed them up (at the expense of using more memory).

```
var pt2pr =
    from mkTPL in personalTemplate.MarketsType
    join mkDB in currentPrintRow.Markets on mkTPL.IDMarketType equals mkDB.IDMarketType
    select new { PersonalTemplate = mkTPL, PrintRow = mkDB };
foreach (var s in pt2pr.Select(p =>
    from selTPL in p.PersonalTemplate.Selections
    join selDB in p.PrintRow.Selections on selTPL.IdSelectionType equals selDB.IdSelectionType
    select new { selTPL, selDB }
)) {
    s.selTPL.OddOrResultValue = s.selDB.OddOrResultValue;
}
```

You can combine LINQ joins into one statement, but using two separate joins looks more readable.

Comment: This changes the values in selTPL?

Comment: @Revious Yes, assuming that items in `PersonalTemplate.Selections` are reference types (classes) not value types (structs). I think this is a fair assumption, given that your current code works.